# Stream tablet to computer with switcher to stream to internet

Tags: software-recommendation, streaming, software, youtube

*I was unsure where to post this, so please move if there is a better site for it*

I am trying to design a cheap system that allows me to have 3 video inputs, allows me to mix them and stream it live to youtube.

Currently I am thinking that I can stream from basic amazon/android tablets to a central computer running OBS. I could mix and apply effects and then stream from OBS to youtube.

My main question is how would I import a stream into OBS and how to create the stream on the tablet.

Overall I would prefer a solution that already exists, but would be able to create an app to do some of the work.

Comment: I don't quite understand the setup you want to use. so you want to stream 3 tablets (the cameras I assume?) to a computer... Are these three cameras supposed to be in frame accurate sync, because then I assume you can bury that idea quickly. If you don't care, what software are you planning to use to stream the tablets to the "main" computer?

Comment: I was able to resolve this by using usb Webcam instead of tablets.

Answer (score 1):

So possibly OBS (i havnt checked) as CasparCG (im using) do not support stream producers (input), I was recently looking into this option, and one program i found (there may be others) that supports this is vmix http://www.vmix.com/software/features.aspx which has a free version.